# How do you use a (parent) class as a gateway / interface to other (child) classes?

Tags: php, oop, php-7

Let's say you have a class named 'Parser' and it acts as a manager to other classes, each related to a different type of parser. I want to be able to call the main Parser class and have it interact with the specific parser provider.

For example:

```
$response = $this->Parser->setProvider('ParserA')->setTemplate($template)->parse($data);
```

This is what I currently have for the main Parser class, but I feel there is a better way and I am also running into a limitation:

```
class Parser
{
private $provider;
public $template;

private function callMethod($provider, $method, $data)
{
    $response = false;

    $class = 'ServiceProviders\Parser\\'.ucfirst($provider);

    if(method_exists($class, $method)) {

        $classInstance = new $class;

        $response = $classInstance->$method($data);

    } else {

        throw new \Exception('INVALID METHOD: '.$class.'->'.$method);
    }

    return $response;
}

public function setProvider($provider)
{
    $this->provider = $provider;

    return $this;
}

public function setTemplate($template)
{
    $this->template = $template;

    return $this;
}

public function parse($data)
{
    $result = null;

    try {

        $result = $this->callMethod($this->provider, __FUNCTION__, $data);

    } catch(\Exception $e) {

        throw new \Exception('There was a problem calling the parser: '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    return $result;
}
}
```

Each parser provider, ParserA, ParserB have methods for parse. The issue that I am having with this approach is that ParserA requires a template and ParserB doesn't.

I am being OCD and I do not want to turn the parameter passed to the parse function into an array. Although the easy solution would be to do that:

```
$parameters = array('data' => $data, 'template' = null);

 callMethod($provider, $method, $parameters);
```

What I want to do is set the $template value for ParserA inside the main Parser class, using the setTemplate() method.

I've tried a few things to do this. I tried turning the Parser class into an interface, but that didnt solve anything (or I didnt understand it). I tried making ParserA extend Parser, but then I could not call the specific parse() method of ParserA, because it then became a method of the parent.

Is there a way to accomplish this that I am overlooking?

Comment: Template depends on input or are templates constants? If there are parsers that require template and those that don't then it's a mistake to set template in a common place which is Parser as it should only know about things that every parser have in common.

Comment: Template is variable. That is a good point that Parser should only know things that are in common.

Comment: So you don't know which parser you creating at the moment? In this case how do you know to set template if you don't know you are calling the one that needs template?

Comment: I know which parser because I am defining that with the setProvider() method. If it doesnt use a template that I wont add setTemplate()

Comment: imo, I would be tempted to have a Parser factory that has two methods makeParser($name) and makeParserUsingTemplate($name, $template). The Parser class has an interface that has the common methods that a parser must provide. This decouples creating a parser from the use of it. Anything that uses a parser will have a typehinted parameter of ParserInterface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the insights from the comments here and other research on the Factory Pattern, I found a solution that solves my question. It also provides a Factory Method that does not use static calls.

```
class Parser
{
private $ParserProvider;

public function __construct( string $provider )
{

    $this->ParserProvider = new \ReflectionClass($provider);

}

public function __invoke($data, $template = null)
{

    $Parser = $this->ParserProvider->newInstance();

    if(isset($template)) {

        return $Parser->setTemplate($template)->parse($data);

    } else {

        return $Parser->parse($data);
    }
}
```

}

And to create a new parser without a template:

```
$ParserA = new Parser('ParserA');
$result = $ParserA($contents);
```

And to create a new parser with a template:

```
$ParserB = new Parser('ParserB');
$result = $ParserB($contents, $template);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is slightly off here: the Parser is a different sort of class from the ParsingHandler, and conflating the two is probably not helping here. Your requirement is classic [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) stuff.

Your Parser should offer the ability to parse, but it shouldn't know what is actually required to do the parsing. Hand that off to a ParsingHandler (in my example, below). A ParsingHandler can do whatever it likes, provided it provides a method the Parser will call to do the actual parsing: in my case `parse()`.

Here's a skeleton:

```
class Parser {

    private $parsingHandler;

    function __construct($parsingHandler){
        $this->parsingHandler = $parsingHandler;
    }

    function parse(){
        return $this->parsingHandler->parse();
    }

}

class TemplatedParsingHandler {

    private $template;

    function __construct($template){
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    function parse(){
        // use the template when parsing
    }
}

class DefaultParsingHandler {

    function parse(){
        // just parses stuff
    }
}

$myTemplatedParsingHandler = new TemplatedParsingHandler($myTemplate);
$myDefaultParsingHandler = new DefaultParsingHandler();

$myTemplatedParser = new Parser($myTemplatedParsingHandler);
$myDefaultParser = new Parser($myDefaultParsingHandler);

$myTemplatdResult = $myTemplatedParser->parse();
$myUntemplatedResult = $myDefaultParser->parse();
```

So the TemplatedParsingHandler knows it needs a template, but the Parser *doesn't* need to know that. It's none of its business: it's not up to it how the TemplatedParsingHandler does the parsing, all it needs to know is that its ParsingHandler has a `parse()` method.

One could use an interface to enforce the minimum `parse()` requirement on the ParseHandlers, but PHP is a dynamic language, so this is kinda counter to its intended coding approach. Duck-tying here is fine. Provided the object you init the Parser with provides a `parse()` method, you don't need to be any more explicit about it than that.

Comment: Thank you for your insights on this. How would you approach this when there are more than two ParseHandlers? For example, 3 might need a template and 2 don't. I am trying to come up with a clean solution that allows for any number of actual parsers, that can be added / changed in the future.

Comment: @sterling I'm not sure I understand the question. The ParseHandlers here are completely decoupled from their usage, so if you need more, just... create more. The use 'em. One thing you could do is if yer Parser oughtn't be coupled to the one ParseHandler, then perhaps you don't want to initialise it with the handler, instead use a set method to set the specific handler closer to "usage time", or even have the parse method take the handler, decoupling it further from the creation of the Parser. Exactly how to approach this is predicated on finer detail than you're providing here.